# send all values from ng repeat in a form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Well I'm generating a ng-repat but I need change data and send all this for edit in back end my problem is when I want to do this, can't obtain values of the form inside ng-repeat
[image]

The picture is the form that have, in html looks:

```
 <form name="FormTablesPackageCreation">
                    <table class="table table-striped ta  ble-bordered">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Estado</th>
                            <th>Especie</th>
                            <th>Tipo</th>
                            <th>Dimension</th>
                            <th>ubicacion</th>
                            <th>largo</th>
                            <th>Ancho</th>
                            <th>Espesor</th>
                            <th>Cantidad</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="packageList in dataListTables">
                                <input class="form-control" type="hidden" ng-value="packageList.id_table"  name="id_table[{{$index}}]" id="id_table[{{$index}}]">
                                <input class="form-control" type="hidden" ng-value="packageList.id_package" name="id_package[{{$index}}]" id="id_package[{{$index}}]">
                                <td>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-value="packageList.estado" ng-model="vm.estado" name="estado[{{$index}}]" id="estado[{{$index}}]" readonly>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-value="packageList.especie" name="especie[{{$index}}]" id="especie[{{$index}}]" readonly>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-value="packageList.ubicacion" name="ubicacion[{{$index}}]" id="ubicacion[{{$index}}]" readonly>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-value="packageList.dimension" name="dimension[{{$index}}]" id="dimension[{{$index}}]" readonly>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-value="packageList.tipo" value="{{packageList.tipo}}" name="tipo[{{$index}}]" id="tipo[{{$index}}]" readonly>
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-value="packageList.humedad" value="{{packageList.humedad}}" name="humedad[{{$index}}]" id="humedad[{{$index}}]" readonly>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-value="packageList.disponible" value="{{packageList.disponible}}" name="disponible[{{$index}}]" id="disponible[{{$index}}]" readonly>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-value="packageList.largo" name="largo[{{$index}}]" id="largo[{{$index}}]" readonly>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-value="packageList.ancho" name="ancho[{{$index}}]" id="ancho[{{$index}}]" readonly>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-value="packageList.espesor" name="espesor[{{$index}}]" id="espesor[{{$index}}]" readonly>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="packageList.cantidad" ng-value="packageList.cantidad" ng-change=""  name="cantidad[{{$index}}]" id="cantidad[{{$index}}]" required>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>Cantidad de tablas</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="vm.total" ng-value="dataListTables | sumByColumn: 'cantidad'" name="total" id="total" readonly>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>Cantidad de tablas nuevo paquete</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="vm.Referencial" ng-value="sumNewCan(dataListTables | sumByColumn: 'cantidad')" readonly>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div>
                        <br>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="crearPaquete()">Crear nuevo Paquetes</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

how I'm trying to obtain of values:

```
$scope.crearPaquete = function ()
{
    var vm = this;
    $scope.seleccionadorEspecies = false;
    $scope.creadorPaquetes = false;
    $scope.verificacionPaquetes = true;

    for (var i = 0; i < FormTablesPackageCreation.cantidad.length; i++)
    {
        console.log(FormTablesPackageCreation.id_table[i].value);
        console.log(FormTablesPackageCreation.id_package[i].value);
        console.log(FormTablesPackageCreation.cantidad[i].value);
    }
};
```

I need obtain data of the ng-repeat, Try another way but do not work yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be trying to get the Data by way of your Form - it should all be model-bound in your HTML to your `dataListTables` collection with the `ng-model` directives (instead of `ng-value`). Since you haven't posted your controller code it's hard to go much further, but assuming your `dataListTables` is a `$scope` variable (which it shouldn't - always assign to a controller variable!!), you could access the data in your controller at any time in the page lifecycle like so:

**HTML**

`<input ... ng-model="packageList.attribute" />` (remove ng-value)

**Controller**

```
angular.forEach($scope.dataListTables, function(obj)
{
    console.log(obj.estado);
    console.log(obj.largo);
    console.log(obj.ancho);
    // and so on
});
```

I'd highly recommend using `ng-controller` with the `as` syntax (`ng-controller="myController as myCtrl"`) and then in your controller code assigning your `dataListTables` to `this` like so:

```
ngApp.controller("myController", function($scope)
{
    this.dataListTables = { ... your data ... };
});
```

Then modify your HTML to access the `myCtrl` variable instead of the implied `$scope`:

`ng-repeat = "packageList in myCtrl.dataListTables"`

For reference, do a quick google on "Angular Dot Rule" to see why using `$scope` variables is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple.
Add ng-model in input tag like this

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-value="packageList.humedad" value="{{packageList.humedad}}" ng-model ="packageList.humedad" name="humedad[{{$index}}]" id="humedad[{{$index}}]" readonly>
```

You can get the updated value in the controller like $scope.dataListTables. hope it will help you.

Comment: `ng-value` should be removed when using `ng-model`. `ng-value` is only for elements like Radio or Checkbox that have to define a "truthy" value.

Comment: Oh yes yes . Thanks a lot @ScottByers for this. i didnot mark it properly.